# Not able to change the array when using add more functionality

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a set of fields which are a part of a form and their value needs to get submitted to the backend
This set of fields can be added multiple times through "add more" functionality.

[Code Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learner001/ywjLsr7e/4/)

For Example - Following are set of values that I add each time if I use "add more" functionality 3 times

```
FirstNameOne
LastNameOne
EmailOne
StatusOne

FirstNameTwo
LastNameTwo
EmailTwo
StatusTwo

FirstNameThree
LastNameThree
EmailThree
StatusThree
```

resulting array that i am getting at backend is in the following form

```
Array
(
    [0] => FirstNameOne
    [1] => FirstNameTwo
    [2] => FirstNameThree
)
Array
(
    [0] => EmailOne
    [1] => EmailTwo
    [2] => EmailThree
)
Array
(
    [0] => StatusOne
    [1] => StatusTwo
    [2] => StatusThree
)
```

However, the format of the array that I want is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => FirstNameOne
    [1] => EmailOne
    [2] => StatusOne
)
Array
(
    [0] => FirstNameTwo
    [1] => EmailTwo
    [2] => StatusTwo
)
Array
(
    [0] => FirstNameThree
    [1] => EmailThree
    [2] => StatusThree
)
```

Can any one please help me with this

HTML Code

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">  
  <button class="add_field_button_per plusbutton">+</button> 
  <input type="text" name="first_name[]" id="first_name" class="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" name="last_name[]" id="last_name" class="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"> 
  <input type="text" name="email[]" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Email"> 
  <select name="action[]">
    <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
    <option value="to">A</option>
    <option value="cc">B</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What you say about following format... is it helpful for you?          
Array
(
    [first_name_1] => 
    [last_name_1] => 
    [email_1] => 
    [action_1] => Inactive
    [first_name_2] => 
    [last_name_2] => 
    [email_2] => 
    [action_2] => Inactive
    [first_name_3] => 
    [last_name_3] => 
    [email_3] => 
    [action_3] => Inactive
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change initial `name` attributes of four elements like below:-

```
name="data[1][]"
name="data[1][]"
name="data[1][]"
name="data[1][]"
```

And then change jQuery code `name` attribute too:-

```
$(wrapper).append('<br><input type="text" name="data['+x+'][]" id="first_name" class="first_name" placeholder="First Name"><input type="text" name="data['+x+'][]" id="last_name" class="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"><input type="text" name="data['+x+'][]" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Email"><select name="data['+x+'][]"><option value="Inactive">Inactive</option><option value="to">To</option><option value="cc">CC</option></select>'); //add input box
```

Working fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/q52v231u/

Comment: Yes I have jquery code, it is updated in the fiddle whose link is in post. I tried your way but it is just creating additional array and not giving the desired result

Comment: in jquery won't the name of the parameters be different?

Comment: what expected outcome you want based on that you have to change jquery `name` attribute too. that's why i used `x` as a parameter there so that it increase the indexes by-default

Comment: Thanks, understood why you used same name

Comment: @sammy  glad to help you :):)